# How do you remove the app id from the url on google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've seen many existing apps that use the url in the form http://something.appspot.com/

But when I added an app yesterday, my urls are in the form http://myapp-3293.appspot.com/  (where 3293 is some random application ID).

If I try http://myapp.appspot.com/ I get 404 Not Found.

How can I remove that app ID from the URL so they are more friendly? How do those other apps have a shorter name?

Comment: Your app ID is "myapp-3293". Those that got "something.appspot.com" is because he registered "something" as an appID when it was still available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a project/app you can choose to customise the app ID.

You can then try to find an app that is available.

Auto generated ones tend to include numeric for common names.